# Why ul classes are both in one li?

Tags: html, css

Why my first li after ul class="B" have both ul type?

```
<ul class="a">
  <li>
    <h2>To care for a cat you will need to:</h2>
  </li>
  <li>
  <ul class="b">
```

I mean it should be only square but next to square is circle too)  and it only works in first "li". After first li (in class="B" all is normal (square is only there). The circle and square are both in this li "li Provide plenty of human companionship /li"

```css
ul>li>ul.b {
  list-style-type: square;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

ul.a {
  list-style-type: circle;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="a">
  <li>
    <h2>To care for a cat you will need to:</h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul class="b">
      <li>Provide plenty of human companionship</li>
      <li>Provide regular, suitable meals with a constant supply of fresh water</li>
      <li>Provide a clean and comfortable bed</li>
      <li>Provide the cat with outdoor access or be prepared to empty and clean a litter tray on a daily basis</li>
      <li>Provide it with a stimulating and safe environment</li>
      <li>Groom it regularly. Longhaired cats require daily grooming</li>
      <li>Have it neutered between 4 and 6 months old</li>
      <li>Vaccinate against the major feline diseases regularly</li>
      <li>Worm regularly and provide treatment for fleas</li>
      <li>Take the cat to the vet when it shows any sign of illness</li>
      <li>Insure your cat or make sure you can afford the cost of any veterinary treatment it may need</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details.

Comment: I made you a snippet.  Please add relevant HTML in a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Your `<ul class="a">` element contains 2 `<li>`s.  One contains an `<h2>` and the other contains a `<ul>`.

You can't make a CSS rule to detect which `<li>` contains a `<ul>`, but you can make a rule to only apply the styles to the 1st `<li>`.  Then you can hide the bullet point on the other `<li>`s.

Like:

```
ul.a > li:first-child {
  list-style-type: circle;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

ul.a > li:not(:first-child) {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

---

Updated demo:

```css
ul > li > ul.b {
  list-style-type: square;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

ul.a > li:first-child {
  list-style-type: circle;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

ul.a > li:not(:first-child) {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="a">
  <li>
    <h2>To care for a cat you will need to:</h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul class="b">
      <li>Provide plenty of human companionship</li>
      <li>Provide regular, suitable meals with a constant supply of fresh water</li>
      <li>Provide a clean and comfortable bed</li>
      <li>Provide the cat with outdoor access or be prepared to empty and clean a litter tray on a daily basis</li>
      <li>Provide it with a stimulating and safe environment</li>
      <li>Groom it regularly. Longhaired cats require daily grooming</li>
      <li>Have it neutered between 4 and 6 months old</li>
      <li>Vaccinate against the major feline diseases regularly</li>
      <li>Worm regularly and provide treatment for fleas</li>
      <li>Take the cat to the vet when it shows any sign of illness</li>
      <li>Insure your cat or make sure you can afford the cost of any veterinary treatment it may need</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```